# how to insert multiple value from checkbox and insert it in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

```
<tr>
<td><label style="padding-top:10px"> flower </label></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="pol[]" value="lili"/> lili
<input type="checkbox" name="pol[]" value="tulip"/> tulip
<input type="checkbox" name="pol[]" value="rose"/> rose</td>
</tr>
<input class="btn btn-success" name="submit" value="Submit" type="submit">
```

i have input like this and php code like this

```
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        $pol  = implode(",",$_POST['pol']);

        $query ="INSERT INTO data_rs (id_rs) values ('$id')";
        $eksekusi=mysql_query($query);

        if(isset($_POST['pol']))
        {
            include ('inc/konek.php');
            $sql ="INSERT INTO rs_fl(id_rs,id_fl) VALUES ((SELECT id_rs FROM 
 data_rs WHERE id_rs ='$id'),
            (SELECT id_fl FROM poliklinik WHERE Flower  ='$pol'))";
            $ek = mysql_query($sql);
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<script> alert ('please insert data !'); window.history.back()</script>";
    }
```

and i have 3 table 'data_rs','poliklinik','rs_fl'each of them contain

```
    data_rs                poliklinik                       rs_fl    
id_rs    name            id_fl      Flower           id(AI)  id_rs  id_fl
r01       type41          f01        lili           
                          f02        tulip 
                          f03        rose
```

the result i want when i check list multiple value from checkbox is my table `rs_fl` is like this same value `id_rs` have diferent value `id_fl`

```
  data_rs                poliklinik                       rs_fl    
id_rs    name            id_fl      Flower            id(AI)  id_rs id_fl
r01       type41          f01        lili             1     r01     f01
                          f02        tulip            2     r01     f02
                          f03        rose             3     r01     f03
```

but i dont know when i select that check box if just 1 value from `poliklinik` table `rs_fl` can show it but when i select multiple value from checkbox table  `rs_fl` is empty.sorry for my bad english and for still using mysql this is old program.thnx

Comment: PHP's mysql_ API was deprecated a long time ago

Comment: @Strawberry if you read his/her post you would know that he/she is already aware

Comment: @rst unfortunately as soon as I hit that I stop reading

Comment: @Strawberry better stop commenting as well. There is no use in commenting on half read posts

Comment: i knnow this time php using mysqli but ihsve work with old program hh stil using php 5 not support mysqli

Comment: @RST Well there's not much point in supplying deprecated code either.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $pol  = implode(",",$_POST['pol']);
```

You are using $_POST['pol'] before testing if it is set
The `$pol` variable can hold one or many flowers.

```
    $query ="INSERT INTO data_rs (id_rs) values ('$id')";
    $eksekusi=mysql_query($query);

    if(isset($_POST['pol']))
    {
        include ('inc/konek.php');
            $sql ="INSERT INTO rs_fl(id_rs,id_fl) VALUES ((SELECT id_rs FROM 
 data_rs WHERE id_rs ='$id'),
```

You are selecting for `Flower = '$pol'`, but in case $pol holds multiple flowers you are searching for something like Flower='lili,rose'. There is no Flower by that name

```
    (SELECT id_fl FROM poliklinik WHERE Flower  ='$pol'))";
    $ek = mysql_query($sql);
}
else
{
    echo "<script> alert ('please insert data !'); window.history.back()</script>";
```

}

There is a lot that can be done to improve your code but the least thing you should do is to test whether or not $_POST['pol'] is set, and if it has multiple values. If it does you should use `WHERE Flower in  ( $pol values go here)`

```
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        $multiple = false;
        $pol = '';

        if (isset($_POST['pol'])) {
          $pol  =  implode('", "', $_POST['pol']);
          if (count($_POST['pol']) > 1)
             $multiple = true;
        }
        $query ="INSERT INTO data_rs (id_rs) values ('$id')";
        $eksekusi=mysql_query($query);

        if ( ! empty($pol) )
        {
            include ('inc/konek.php');
            if ( $multiple )
              $flower = "='". $pol . "'";
            else
              $flower = 'IN ("' . $flower .'" )';

                $sql ="INSERT INTO rs_fl(id_rs,id_fl) VALUES ((SELECT id_rs FROM 
     data_rs WHERE id_rs ='$id'),
                (SELECT id_fl FROM poliklinik WHERE Flower $flower))";
                $ek = mysql_query($sql);
            }
            else
            {
                echo "<script> alert ('please insert data !'); window.history.back()</script>";
        }
```

Not tested so it may still need some finetuning